# Interface with general or special methods?

Tags: java

At the moment I need to save four types of files, movie pictures, movie posters, movie trailers, and user avatars. I want to put photos and posters in the images folder, avatars I want to put in the avatars folder, and trailers in the trailers folder.

My current interface looks like this

```
public interface StorageService {
    String save (
            final File file,
            final String contentType
    ) throws IOException;
...
}
```

to customize the `save` method to place different files I wonder which way to use.

The first way is to add a new parameter `String folder`

```
 public interface StorageService {
    String save (
            final File file,
            final String contentType,
            final String folder
    ) throws IOException;
...
}
```

and in the variable folder, enter the name of the folder to which the file will be added.

The second way is to create three separate methods

```
public interface StorageService {
    String saveImage (
            final File file,
            final String contentType
    ) throws IOException;
    String saveAvatar (
            final File file,
            final String contentType
    ) throws IOException;
    String saveTrailer (
            final File file,
            final String contentType
    ) throws IOException;
...
}
```

What do you think? Which idea is better?

Answer (score 0):

have you checked the Strategy pattern. Here the action that you are performing is the same, however the strategy differs based on some condition. So this pattern should be a perfect fit

Comment: Interesting solution, but it does not suit me a bit. I would have to create three different implementations, which in my opinion will create too much code. In addition, I have not mentioned that I have two implementations of GoogleStorageService and AmazonStorageService, which will make the code a bit complicated.

Comment: It's about saving your regression efforts. Consider if another file type has to be saved. In that case you will change the interface and the corresponding implementations and have to retest all those. Strategy decouples the logic to a single class which can then be tested in isolation. Most of the patterns in general increase verbosity,  but there are long term benefits.